# Unable to print other levels via BOOST_LOG_SEV

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I'm trying to use Boost.Log but when I use:

```
BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, level)//Doesn't matter the level here
```

even if manually pass `error` I'm always getting:

```
[2021-11-05 12:07:01.305178] [0x00007ffff21589c0] [info]
```

I'm expecting `[info]` to reflect the severity level I'm passing.

**[Edit]**

This is the code (Entire code, from .hpp):

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

enum severity_level { trace, debug, info, warning, error, fatal };
inline boost::log::sources::severity_logger<severity_level> slg;

template <class First> std::string extract_args(First first) {
  if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<First>) {
    return std::to_string(first);
  } else {
    return first;
  }
}

template <class First, class... Args> First extract_args(First first, Args... args) {
  first += extract_args(args...);
  return first;
}

template <class First, class... Args> std::string logging_helper(First msg, Args... args) {
  std::string s_msg = extract_args(msg);

  if constexpr (sizeof...(args)) {
    s_msg += extract_args(args...);
  }

  return s_msg;
}

template <class First, class... Args> inline void log(severity_level level, First msg, Args... args) {
  BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, level) << logging_helper(msg, args...);
}
```

If I use as proposed by @Andrey Semashev:

```
boost::log::trivial::severity_level
```

I'm getting following error:

```
cannot convert ‘const boost::log::v2_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level’ to ‘boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<severity_level>::value_type’ {aka ‘severity_level’}
```

Comment: You need to show the code, at least that configures loggers and sinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect, you're using a severity level type different from `boost::log::trivial::severity_level` while still relying on the default sink. If the default sink can't extract severity level from a log record, it will use `boost::log::trivial::severity_level::info` as a default.

You should either use `boost::log::trivial::severity_level` everywhere, or explicitly configure a sink, with a filter and formatter as necessary. In the latter case you can use your own severity level enum:

```
enum severity_level { trace, debug, info, warning, error, fatal };

// Formatting for severity levels
template< typename Char, typename Traits >
inline std::basic_ostream< Char, Traits >& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream< Char, Traits >& strm, severity_level level)
{
    const char* str;
    switch (level)
    {
    case trace: str = "trace"; break;
    case debug: str = "debug"; break;
    default:
    case info: str = "info"; break;
    case warning: str = "warning"; break;
    case error: str = "error"; break;
    case fatal: str = "fatal"; break;
    }
    strm << str;
    return strm;
}

inline boost::log::sources::severity_logger<severity_level> slg;

BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_timestamp, "TimeStamp",
    boost::log::attributes::utc_clock::value_type)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_thread_id, "ThreadID",
    boost::log::attributes::current_thread_id::value_type)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_severity, "Severity", severity_level)

// Logging initialization. To be called early in main().
void init_logging()
{
    auto core = boost::log::core::get();

    // Add commonly used attributes, such as timestamp, thread id, etc.
    core->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp", boost::log::attributes::utc_clock());
    core->add_global_attribute(
        "ThreadID", boost::log::attributes::current_thread_id());

    // Construct the sink
    typedef boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink<
        boost::log::sinks::text_ostream_backend > text_sink;
    boost::shared_ptr< text_sink > sink = boost::make_shared< text_sink >();

    boost::shared_ptr< std::ostream > stream(&std::clog, boost::null_deleter());
    sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(stream);

    // Set formatter
    sink->set_formatter(
        boost::log::expressions::stream << "["
            << boost::log::expressions::format_date_time(a_timestamp, "%Y-%M-%d %H:%M:S.%f")
            << "] [" << a_thread_id
            << "] [" << a_severity
            << "] " << boost::log::expressions::smessage);

    // Add the sink to core
    core->add_sink(sink);
}

// ...

template <class First, class... Args> inline void log(severity_level level, First msg, Args... args) {
  BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, level) << logging_helper(msg, args...);
}
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for the reply. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Looks like my answer applies. The error you're getting is because you left your enum somewhere, possibly in the `slg` logger type.

Comment: Ok, do you mind showing me how to do it properly because tbh I simply don't know. I find that that is working with this lib very frustrating. There seems to be lots of things (not as straightforward as you think) to actually make it running. 
As for:
>> The error you're getting is because you left your enum somewhere, possibly in the slg logger type...
Please look carefully at the updated edit. slg is literally on the second line after includes. This is actually the entire code, so you can check for yourself the behavior.

Comment: In the code you posted, the logger type is `severity_logger<severity_level>`, where `severity_level` is your enum, not the `boost::log::trivial::severity_level` that is supported by the default sink. This is also implied by the compiler error. Hence my answer applies.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed helped. Still, surely, the default severity_level should be the one from your lib so users don't have to do anything just use it? Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of using your own enum.